# How do i find the path to startup folder?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, windows-10, windows-xp, windows-vista

Im currently working on a project that requires me to insert the **path** to the **startup folder**. I need my code to work on all Windows versions from Windows XP to Windows 10.

So **what im asking for** is the **path to the startup folder on all Windows versions** from Windows XP forward.

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp
```

It should be the same on all versions. Just type it in in the explorer and you should get it.

Here a few other ways https://thetechhacker.com/2017/01/07/how-to-access-windows-10-startup-folder/

Answer (score 2):

Not enough points to comment yet, so just some info for anyone else who comes across this...

1. You should never hard code these paths because the location can differ from PC to PC. You should always use Environment Variables instead.
2. "C:\ProgramData..." only applies to Windows 7 onwards. That location is incorrect for XP and therefore doesn't answer the question.

The correct location for all versions from XP onwards is

```
"%USERPROFILE%\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
```

or from Windows 7 onwards, you can also use

```
"%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
```

which ponts to the same location.

Don't forget that you will usually need to include the quotes as well, because there are spaces in the path.